# How to make a view not updatable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view

I am using PostgreSQL to store business data in large amount for data warehousing purpose. I am writing views to customize the materialized tables.

I am wondering whether it is possible to set a view not updatable.

I have checked [the postgresql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createview.html), but found no specific answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have updatable views, you have to create RULE's to make this possible. Without these extra rules, you can't do an update on a view.

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-views.html):

> What happens if a view is named as the
>   target relation for an INSERT, UPDATE,
>   or DELETE? After doing the
>   substitutions described above, we will
>   have a query tree in which the result
>   relation points at a subquery
>   range-table entry. This will not work,
>   so the rewriter throws an error if it
>   sees it has produced such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is out-of-date - PostgreSQL currently supports updatable views so the question is actually relevant:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rules-views.html#RULES-VIEWS-UPDATE

In order to make a view non-updatable, one simply needs to avoid granting the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE privileges on any role for the view (or revoke such privileges if they are already granted).

Credit for the answer goes to RhodiumToad (https://twitter.com/rhodiumtoad, https://github.com/RhodiumToad)

Answer (score 0):

Views in PostreSQL aren't updatable.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers, you can add `OFFSET 0` to your query, i.e:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS (SELECT * FROM my_table OFFSET 0);
```

Inserting into *my_view* now will generate an error:

> Views containing LIMIT or OFFSET are not automatically updatable.